# Simulate tab key press automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, keyboard, accessibility

I am working on project in which i have created a chrome plugin.
In that plugin i have button and on clicking of that button keyboard tab key must automatically start getting pressed so that i can check if focus is getting trapped on some elements or not.

I have created a code in javascript where I have used keydown event with keycode 9, but seems this is not pressing tab key automatically to move focus to next element.

I am expecting that keyboard tab key must automatically get press so that focus trap issue can be caught

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=trigger+tab+key+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)